# running "last" printed suspicious output

Tags: last

I invoked

```
last
```

from bash on my personal computer and I have this output

```
user     pts/2        :0               Wed Jul 27 09:15   still logged in   
user     pts/1        :0               Wed Jul 27 09:13   still logged in   
user     pts/0        :0               Wed Jul 27 09:13   still logged in   
user     console      :0               Wed Jul 27 09:12   still logged in
```

funny thing is that I have 2 terminals active and it looks like there is more users logged in.... is this ok? (I am curious what is 'pts/0' and 'console' because these entries are suspicious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `:0` in the command tell that you are locally connected to X-window interface.

You must have also 3 terminal open at the time you issue `last` command.

a remote connection look like

```
archemar pts/0        172.16.17.85     Wed Jul 27 09:10   still logged in
archemar pts/0        172.16.17.85     Tue Jul 26 17:08 - 17:08  (00:00)
```

- `pts/0` is a pseudo terminal